# C++ addition operator overloading multiple times

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

i am trying to get some mathematical construct working which contains 'Cells' which represent a mathematical function with a set of inputs and outputs.

Each mathematical operation gets their own class which inherits from `Cell`. Using some operator overloading, I would like to spawn a new `Add`-Cell when i call `operator+` on two cells.

This works fine so far but I encountered a problem.

I have written a small demo code which illustrates my problem:

Imagine this class which fully implements copy/move assignment/construction as well as a custom destructor and a constructor.

```cpp
class Cell{

private:
    Cell* A = nullptr;
    Cell* B = nullptr;
public:
    Cell() {
        std::cout << "default constructed" << std::endl;
    }
    Cell(Cell& A, Cell& B) {
        this->A = &A;
        this->B = &B;
        std::cout << "default constructed" << std::endl;
    }
    T(const Cell& other){
        this->A = other.A;
        this->B = other.B;
        std::cout << "copy constructed" << std::endl;

    }
    T(Cell&& other){
        this->A = other.A;
        this->B = other.B;
        std::cout << "move constructed" << std::endl;

    }
    Cell& operator=(Cell&& other){
        this->A = other.A;
        this->B = other.B;
        std::cout << "move assigned" << std::endl;
        return *this;

    }
    Cell& operator=(const Cell&& other){
        this->A = other.A;
        this->B = other.B;
        std::cout << "copy assigned" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }

    Cell operator+(Cell& other){
        return T{*this, other};
    }

    virtual ~Cell() {
        std::cout << "destructed" << std::endl;
    }

};
```

It is similar to my code. Here `Cell` can be considered any type of cell with 2 previous mathematical operations.

So the issue arises when I try to do something like this:

```cpp
    Cell t1{};
    Cell t2{};
    Cell t3{};

    auto h = t1 + t2 + t3;
```

It creates 3 empty `Cell` objects. Then it creates a new `Cell` based on `t1` and `t2` and uses that to create a new `Cell` together with `t3`. The issue here is that the first `Cell = t1 + t2` will be destructed directly after that operation and the final tree will hold an invalid reference.

This problem could easily be overcome by doing this:

```cpp
    auto h1 = t1 + t2;
    auto h  = h1 + t3;
```

or using `new` inside the overloaded addition operator `operator+`.

---

I would like to not use `new` inside the operator since cleaning them up eventually could only be achieved by using some sort of tracking system.

I was wondering if there is a nice solution to this problem.

I am very happy for any advice or help.

Comment: Side note: `T` is usually used as template parameter not as a class name. Most developers respect this convention and get use to it. So for them it will be harder to read this code, since their minds are trained to read `T`  as template parameter.

Comment: I will quickly adjust.

Comment: the issue with copying would be that i could not use `t1-t3` afterwards, right? Also how would this be realised inside the operator?

Comment: Mhm... So there seems to be no solution beside boost? In my actual code, I usually define the `leafs` inside the tree which are usually some variables which hold some value. When creating a copy of those, I wont be able to adjust their values and impact the output of the function.

Comment: No Boost is not the solution. Doing what Boost do could be the solution. One thing that springs to mind is to consider a + b + c as a + b returning a proxy object, and you define the operator proxy object + Cell.

Comment: I have never worked with proxies. I will look into that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 2021 so use C++11 `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique` from `C++14`.

```cpp
class Cell{

private:
    using ptr = std::unique_ptr<Cell>;
    ptr A;
    ptr B;

public:
    Cell() {
        std::cout << "default constructed" << std::endl;
    }

    Cell(Cell&& A, Cell&& B) {
        this->A = std::make_unique<Cell>(std::move(A));
        this->B = std::make_unique<Cell>(std::move(B));
        std::cout << "default constructed" << std::endl;
    }

    T(Cell&& other){
        this->A = std::move(other.A);
        this->B = std::move(other.B);
        std::cout << "move constructed" << std::endl;

    }
    Cell& operator=(Cell&& other){
        this->A = std::move(other.A);
        this->B = std::move(other.B);
        std::cout << "move assigned" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }

    Cell operator+(Cell&& other) && {
        return T{std::move(*this), std::move(other)};
    }

    ptr clone() const {
        if (this)
            return std::make_unique<Cell>(A->clone(), B->clone());
        return nullptr;
    }

    virtual ~Cell() {
        std::cout << "destructed" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

If you need actual copy constructors assignments then utilize `clone` method.

Or you can use `shared_ptr`, but in this case it would be safer `Cell` to be not mutable.